# Focus effect on a DOM element in React

Tags: reactjs, dom

I'd like to add some kind of overlay-focus effect on an element in React.

I create a custom hook to override the default behavior of the contextMenu in my app.

When right-clicking on a certain element, I'd like to display my context menu and add an overlay to focus that element.

So far, the only method that I found was to add 4 more divs to my dom, as you can see here (1 is the overlays, 2 is my focused div, 3 is the context menu).

These divs positionning is based on the return value of `getBoundingClientRect`

[image: 1 is the overlays, 2 is my focused div, 3 is the context menu]

Obviously, this is messy as hell, but I just can't think of a way to actually get this effect (I'm not good in CSS, so maybe there's an easy way to do so)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone needs it, here's the CSS that I used to get this effect :

```
.maskFocus {
  border: 3px solid #efecff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 2; /* anything above the focused div */
  box-shadow: #31353944 0px 0px 0px 5000px;
}
```